# Doctrine 2.0 | Create Database | Are Foreign Keys Unique

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, doctrine-orm

1. I'm using Doctrine 2.0 and the latest version of MySQL aswell as PHP 5.3.5
2. I currently use PHP mapping to create my database.

I have a model (Event) which has a one2one relationship with another model (EventInvitations) - this should probably be one2many but lets move on from that.

My current mapping for EventInvitations has a UniqueConstraint on an eventid and a userid.
My EventInivitation also has a OneToOne Join on Event, this is a Foreign Key

when i run: "doctrine.php orm:schema-tool:update --force" Doctrine will successfully create my Unique index but it also seems to create another Uniq index which has a key name like Uniq_AHJHAUSH7J but on EventId field.

The problem is that i dont want the Foreign Key to create a Unique Field.  Is there a way for me to tell Doctrine not to create the Unique index for the foreign key?

Comment: Would that not be getting created as a result of the OneToOne mapping, causing a unique constraint?  I assume you have your primary keys defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A OneToOne relationship implies uniqueness. It means that for a given EventInvitation there is one Event, and vice-versa.

You probably want several EventInvitations to be associated with one Event, and in that case the relationship should be ManyToOne (from the perspective of EventInvitation); as such you will be able to have the foreign key to an Event without the unique index.

Comment: Yes you're right Faken.  I understood the difference but didnt expect Doctrine to do what it did.  This is now fixed and working.  Thanks!